# Elasticsearch filter in Aggregation data

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to make query that like 'sql having' in ES java api.

```
select * from table group by oid having count(1) > 10
```

Here is I made but cannot add filter method.

```
.aggregation( 
            AggregationBuilders.terms( "aggs").field( "oid").filter... // cannot add filter method
```

Should I use .script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`min_doc_count` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3) for this:

```
.aggregation( 
        AggregationBuilders.terms("aggs")
             .field( "oid")
             .minDocCount(10)                 <----- add this
```